# Nativescript TextField text/number limit

Tags: textfield, nativescript

I noticed that nativescript has no limit/max xml attribute for textfield max text/number input limit which is pretty much must have thing or am I not noticing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use NativeScript [masked input plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-maskedinput), which would allow you to specify the number of chars and specific format.

Comment: This works BUT only problem is that I can delete those mask marks and then I get IndexOutOfBoundsException and app crashes there.. solves problem and creates new one.

Comment: Separator . is not working and more important binding with maskedInput is not supported?

Comment: I tested data binding with `nativescript-maskedinput` plugin and it is working. You could review my sample project here - https://github.com/tsonevn/maskedInput_question38346232.git. In regard to that there was a problem with data binding in previous plugin version, but it has been fixed in the new version - https://github.com/bthurlow/nativescript-maskedinput/issues/3.  About the separators, you could review the info in npm -https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-maskedinput#supported-seperators.